# Вызов контекстного меню в sublime text 3

Tags: ide, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Как вызвать контекстное меню в боковом сайдбаре ST3 (кроме клика правой кнопкой мыши)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках горячих клавиш пробовал повесить команду на различные комбинации:

```
{ "keys": ["xf86wakeup"], "command": "context_menu" }
{ "keys": ["fn"], "command": "context_menu" }
{ "keys": ["ctrl+h"], "command": "context_menu" }
```

Но ни один способ не заработал.
В первом варианте контекстное меню работает в системных горячих клавишах (такое распознается нажатие на fn).

Как вызвать контекстное меню в st3?